# infimum of a set of stopping times

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $(Y^a: a\in \Lambda)$ be  a set of random processes given by
$$Y^a(s) = \int_0^s \sigma^a(r) dW(r)$$
where $W$ is Brownian motion w.r.t. filtered probability space
$(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P, \mathcal{F}_t)$, $\sigma^a(\cdot)$ is
uniformly bounded predictable process, s.t. $|\sigma^a(r)|<1$ for all
$r$ and $a$. 
Let $\theta^a = \inf(s>0, Y^a(s) \ge 1)$ be a stopping time.

[Q.] Is the following true,
$$\inf_{a\in \Lambda} (\theta^a) >0, \quad a.s.-P$$

When $\Lambda$ is finite set, it is clearly true. But, I am not sure
otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: It is not true even if all $\sigma^a$ are deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Fix some $t>0$, and define $t^n_k = \frac{k}{n}.t$ for $0 \leq k \leq n$. Define $\Lambda$ as the set of deterministic, $\{-1,1\}$-valued processes and $\Lambda_n$ as the subset of $\Lambda$ such that $\sigma \in \Lambda_n$ if it is constant on each $(t^n_k,t^n_{k+1})$.

Since brownian motion has unbounded variation, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_k|W_{t^n_{k+1}}-W_{t^n_k}|=+\infty$ a.s., in particular it is greater than $1$ for some $n$. Then notice that (for each $\omega$) this sum is equal to the brownian integral corresponding to some $\sigma \in \Lambda_n$. Hence $\inf_{a\in\Lambda}\theta^a < t$ a.s. for all $t>0$.

Comment: The argument is not completely correct. However, it is possible to make it correct. E.g. saying that $\inf \theta_a > 0$ a.s. implies $\inf \theta_a>c$ with a positive probability for some $c>0$ and further speaking of the variation on the interval $[0,c]$.

Comment: Since for each $t>0$, $\inf_a \theta^a <t$ a.s., then this inf is $0$ almost surely.

Comment: Your claim may not be true. 
In fact, suppose $\sigma_k$ be the value of $\sigma(r)$ in interval $(t_k^n,
t_{k+1}^n)$, which must be $\mathcal{F}_{t_k^n}$ measurable random
variable. Then, your claim implicitly assumed 
$\sigma_k \cdot (W(t_{k+1}^n) - W(t_k^n)) = |W(t_{k+1}^n) -
W(t_k^n)|$. But this is only possible for $\sigma_k$, which is the
difference of two indicator
r.v.s on the event $W(t_{k+1}^n) - W(t_k^n)>0$ and  $W(t_{k+1}^n) -
W(t_k^n)<0$. As a result, such a $\sigma_k$ is not
$\mathcal{F}_{t_k^n}$ measurable. Please let me know, if I made some
misunderstanding. 

Comment: @kenneth : I am saying that for each fixed $\omega$, there will be some $\sigma$ such that $\sum_k |W_{t_{k+1}} - W_{t_k}| = \int \sigma dW$. This is different than saying that you can find $\sigma$ s.t. the equality is true for all $\omega$. For instance for $n=1$, this is just saying that $|W_t - W_0|$ is either equal to $(W_t - W_0)$ or to $(-1).(W_t - W_0)$, but of course none of these equalities are true with probability $1$.