# infimum of  a set of positive r.v. with the same distribution

Tags: pr.probability

Let $Y$ be real valued random variable on probability space $(\Omega,
\mathcal{F}, P)$, such that $Y>0$ almost surely. Suppose $(X^a: a\in
\Lambda)$ be a set of random 
variables in the same probability space with the same distribution as
$Y$.

[Q.] Is the following true?
$$\inf_a (X^a) >0, \quad a.s.-P$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, certainly not.  Let $Y \sim U(0,1)$, so $Y > 0$ a.s.  If $\{X^a : a \in \mathbb{N}\}$ are iid $U(0,1)$, then it is easy to see that $\inf_a X^a = 0$ a.s.  In fact this will be true for any $Y$ with essential infimum $0$.

Comment: Hi, Nate, Would you see another question, 
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/56741/infimum-of-a-set-of-stopping-times

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $Y$ is equal to 1/n with probability $2^{-n}$, and suppose your index set is infinite.  Then $Y>0$ always, but your infimum is $0$ with probability 1.